# Random variables with values in the circle $\mathbb{T}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, fourier-transform

I am trying to solve the problem 10.22 from Folland's book "Real analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications".

If $\{X_j\}$ is a sequence of independent random variables in the unitary circle $\mathbb{T}$ with a common distribution $\lambda$ supported on a finite subgroup $Z_m=\{e^{2\pi i \frac{j}{m}}: 0\leq j <m \}$, then the distribution of $\prod_{i=1}^n X_j$ converges vaguely to $\frac{1}{m}\sum_{z \in Z_m} \delta_z$ on $Z_m$.

The hint is to use the following exercise: If $\mu$ is a positive Borel measure on $\mathbb{T}$ with $\mu(\mathbb{T})=1$ that is a linear combination, with positive coefficientes, of the point masses at $0, \frac{1}{m}, \dots, \frac{m-1}{m}$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\hat{\mu}(jm)=1$ for all $j \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I think that the idea is to prove that the Fourier transform of the  convolution $\lambda*\cdots *\lambda$ converges pointwise to the Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{m}\sum_{z \in Z_m} \delta_z$ but I can't find a way to solve this. Can any one help me?

Edit: We can use that $P_{X_1\cdot X_2\cdot X\cdots X_n}=\lambda *\cdots *\lambda$, meaning the distribution of the product is the convolution of $\lambda$'s.

Comment: This doesn't matter much, but in my edition of Folland, this is exercise 10.22. Maybe this is a difference of editions. Regardless, it's good that you wrote out the relevant information anyways, as it's good practice on this website to write your questions in such a way that responders don't need to have any "reference materials" on hand.

Comment: You're right @AJY . I apologize for my mistake. I already fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I will represent $\mathbb{T}$ as $[0, 1]$ instead of the circle in the complex plane. So $Z_m = \{0, 1/m, \ldots, (m-1)/m\}$

The Fourier transform of $\lambda * \cdots * \lambda$ is $\hat{\lambda}^n$.
We have $$\hat{\lambda}(\kappa) = \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} e^{-2 \pi i \kappa j/m}\lambda(\{j/m\})$$
for integers $\kappa$.
By the triangle inequality, $|\hat{\lambda}(\kappa)| \le 1$. Equality occurs if and only if $e^{-2\pi i \kappa j/m} = 1$ for all $j$, that is, if $\kappa$ is an integer multiple of $m$. [This is Exercise 8.39, where you have forgotten to quote an important part of the exercise: that we have the strict inequality $|\hat{\lambda}(\kappa)| < 1$ when $\kappa$ is not an integer multiple of $m$.]

Thus,
$$(\hat{\lambda}(\kappa))^n \to \begin{cases}
0 & \text{$\kappa$ not integer multiple of $m$,}
\\
1 & \text{$\kappa$ integer mulitple of $m$.}
\end{cases}$$

The Fourier transform of $\nu := \frac{1}{m} \sum_{z \in Z_m} \delta_z$ is
$$\hat{\nu}(\kappa)
= \frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} e^{-2\pi i \kappa j/m}
=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{$\kappa$ not integer multiple of $m$,}
\\
1 & \text{$\kappa$ integer mulitple of $m$.}
\end{cases}$$
for integers $\kappa$.

Comment: It was not so much as I "forgot the detail" as I "didn't understand exercise 8.39 properly". I read as there could exist other non multiples of m which could bring the fourier coeficient to have module 1.
I wrote it down and filled in the details.
Thank you so much @angryavian.